# Log4net UDP Appender in Windows Service

Tags: udp, log4net, appender, topshelf

I have a very simple Windows service developed using TopShelf. I'm using log4net and have a UDP Appender configured. I'm using an app called Log2Console to view the UDP logs.

Everything works fine when I run the app as an exe and I can see the UDP logs in Log2Console. However, when I install the exe as a service using TopShelf and start it I don't see any UDP logs.

I've tried turning off the Windows Firewall to see if that would make a difference but it did not. I've also tried changing the service logon details but no luck there either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is most likely a permissions issue. However, can you use a file appender as a service and validate that the service is starting up correct and generating log messages?

Comment: Added a file appender but it's not updating when I run as a service. Should have checked that. Just assumed it was UDP related, having never used that appender before. The service is definitely running as I added a few lines of code to delete files from a folder periodically.

Comment: I tried running the service under Admin a/c but not luck. Also granted permissions on log file directory to Everyone.

Comment: If you're not appending to a file appender, then the service may not be starting up correctly. Joining the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topshelf-discuss we might be able to help you out at bit more (and you're not waiting on just me to respond).

Comment: Found the problem... silly silly mistake on my part. So obvious I can't believe I missed it a few days ago. First line in my Main method was  XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(....) . Of course that code never gets called when running as a service. Doooooooooh. In my defense it's the first service I wrote in nearly 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue and had to update the HostFactory set up to include log4net configuration within WhenStarted:

```
s.WhenStarted(lcp => 
{
   // configure logging for hosted service
   XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(".\\log4net.config"));
   lcp.Start();
});
```